# JSDoc - Correct way to document a method which potentially returns any type?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have a utility function which returns a value from your array. However, your array could obviously contain elements of any type, so how do I document that the return type is mixed?

In PHPdoc I would use:

```
@return mixed
```

What is the JSDoc equivalent?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use asterisk in JSDoc

```
@returns {*}
```

Or also, if you know all possible types, you can separate them by pipes

```
@returns {String|Number|Boolean}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSDoc documentation says about [type expressions](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html):

> You can use any Google Closure Compiler type expression...

The [linked page on the Closure Compiler docs](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#types) says:

> The ALL type    `{*}`    Indicates that the variable can take on any type.

So you may use `@returns {*}` for a function that can return any type.